# dynamic sql query for inserting week and month

Tags: sql

I want to create a table. This is the create table script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimTenure1]
(
   [TenureWeekID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [TenureWeek] [smallint] NOT NULL,
   [TenureWeekBand] ,
   [TenureMonth] [smallint] NOT NULL,
   [TenureMonthBand] ,
)
```

I have to create `TenureWeekBand` and `TenureMonthBand` dynamic.

For eg when user enter 1 in `TenureWeek` automatically calculated in `TenureWeekBand` showing below.

What can I define in create table script for `TenureWeekBand` and `TenureMonthBand` columns?

Table

```
TenureWeek         TenureWeek                TenureMonth              [TenureMonthBand]
  1              week of 1 enrollment              1                month of 1 enrollment
  2              week of 2 enrollment              1                month of 1 enrollment
  3              week of 3 enrollment              1                month of 1 enrollment
  4              week of 4 enrollment              1                month of 1 enrollment
  5              week of 5 enrollment              2                month of 2 enrollment  
  6              week of 6 enrollment              2                month of 2 enrollment
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) for this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimTenure1]
(
   [TenureWeekID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [TenureWeek] [smallint] NOT NULL,
   [TenureWeekBand] AS ('week of ' + CAST(TenureWeek AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' enrollment') PERSISTED,
   [TenureMonth] [smallint] NOT NULL,
   [TenureMonthBand] AS ('month of ' + CAST(Tenuremonth AS VARCHAR(2)) + ' enrollment') PERSISTED,
)
```

It probably wouldn't hurt to question if this is truly necessary, though, as it's something that could easily be added to a view (or report), saving you storage space and speeding up the process of inserting / updating data in your table.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the edit to my question - it's generally better to point it out in a comment before making the edit (or do both), but I don't mind!

Comment: am sorry , buts it should change whenevr change in week id and all the columns should be dynamic except id

Comment: i need to inserts week id and based on that the other columns should be automatically updated so can you give insert statement for this query

Comment: In other words, you also need to define TenureMonth?

Comment: Or are you also trying to create TenureWeek, too?  And if you're trying to do either, why didn't you put it in your question?

Comment: am sorry can help me in achiveing that table dynamically

Comment: Again, let me try to say it clearly: what are you trying to do?  Do you want an insert script that populates all the columns?  If so, what is the logic for each column? Obviously, since I've spent two hours responding to comments and questions, I'm willing to help you out; but you need to provide the information necessary to make this work.  I'm not a mind-reader.